# ArrayList<Model> showing wrong values

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite

I have created a database which stores group details.I want to show that group details in a listview.But when i open my app i only see the the last values in the database.why this is happening???

Getting Value from database

```
public ArrayList<GroupModel> getAllGroups() {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "Select * From " + tableName;
        GroupModel groupModel;
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            getGroupInfo = new ArrayList<GroupModel>();
            groupModel = new GroupModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(groupName)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(createdOn)));
            getGroupInfo.add(groupModel);

        }
        return getGroupInfo;
    }
```

When i debugged my

```
1st iteration List value[0]="A","B"
2nd iteration List value[0]="p","q";
```

why this is happeninng, the desired outcome should be

```
1st iteration List value[0]="A","B"
2nd iteration List value[1]="p","q";
```

Model Class

```
public class GroupModel {

    private String groupId, groupName, groupCreatedDate, contactId, contactName, contactNumber;

    public GroupModel() {
    }

    public GroupModel(String groupName, String groupCreatedDate) {

        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.groupCreatedDate = groupCreatedDate;
    }

    public GroupModel(String groupId, String contactId, String contactName, String contactNumber) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.contactId = contactId;
        this.contactName = contactName;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public String getGroupCreatedDate() {
        return groupCreatedDate;
    }

    public void setGroupCreatedDate(String groupCreatedDate) {
        this.groupCreatedDate = groupCreatedDate;
    }

    public String getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }

    public void setContactId(String contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794551/fetch-data-from-existing-sqlite-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
            getGroupInfo = new ArrayList<GroupModel>();
            groupModel = new GroupModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(groupName)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(createdOn)));
            getGroupInfo.add(groupModel);

        }
```

you initializing arrayList everytime.
you have to initialize arrayList before and outside  while loop.

Answer (score 3):

you are creating to much groupInfo object. Move its instantiation out the while loop

```
getGroupInfo = new ArrayList<GroupModel>();
while (c.moveToNext()) {   
        groupModel = new GroupModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(groupName)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(createdOn)));
        getGroupInfo.add(groupModel);

    }
```

Comment: Ok thankz :)Sir one more thing ,how to get the latest value added to the array list

Comment: with `getGroupInfo.get(getGroupInfo.size() - 1);`

Comment: @user3844417 - A quick way might be to change your `add(groupModel)` method to `add(0,groupModel)`. Then you could just use `.get(0);`

Comment: @Rudi i want to insert an ArrayList values in to the database.How can i achieve it????

Comment: @blackbelt i want to insert ArrayList values into the database.how can i achieve it???

Answer (score 2):

After only a brief glance through your code you appear to be re-instantiating your `ArrayList` variable each time the loop runs here;

```
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        getGroupInfo = new ArrayList<GroupModel>(); // <-- HERE!
        groupModel = new GroupModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(groupName)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(createdOn)));
        getGroupInfo.add(groupModel);
    }
    return getGroupInfo;
```

This means when you `return getGroupInfo`, it can only ever be an `ArrayList` with one element. Instead, you should be instantiating your `getGroupInfo` variable **before** the loop starts, like so;

```
    getGroupInfo = new ArrayList<GroupModel>(); // Moved to here.
    while (c.moveToNext()) {       
        groupModel = new GroupModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(groupName)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(createdOn)));
        getGroupInfo.add(groupModel);
    }
```

I hope this helps.